# Permissions needed to copy a file to a UNC share

Tags: asp.net, permissions

I'm working on and ASP.NET app. A key functionality is that it copies a pdf document to a share on FILE_SERVER_1. I'm using the System.IO.File.Copy method to copy the file.

When I run locally (from the debugger), everything works fine. When I run the app from WEB_SERVER_1, I get an UnauthorizedAccessException. I presume that this is because on the server, the app is running as the NETWORK SERVICE. I've given NETWORK SERVICE Modify and Write privileges on the folder and on the share on FILE_SERVER_1, but I still get the exception.

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://serverfault.com/questions/41130/network-service-account-accessing-a-folder-share